# PortAudio: Play multiple generated sounds by calling function

Tags: c++, audio, portaudio

I've started to play with PortAudio library about week ago. I've checked most of tutorial/test examples but haven't seen solution for what I need. I'm making simple sequencer - I've already done drawing sounds as blocks on the piano roll, but now I need make it sound somehow. I wonder if there is possibility to get it working like this:

- run a method that will play one sound,
- give frequency and duration of sound as parameters to that method,
- play multiple sounds(i.e. three sounds at the same time, bu calling three methods).

In example files it looks more complicated. When I want to play multiple sine waves, so I have to merge all that waves, and then give that data to stream.

Maybe someone got better solutions to resolve this problem?

Comment: Most audio devices don't support playing multiple files simultaneously so you will have to create a simple mixer to do that. This is fairly simple as long as your files have the same sampling rate. Even though you haven't specified it, it seems that you want to create a tone generator. Again, there are many resources online so check them out. Not familiar if PortAudio supports any of that.

Comment: Yes, I want to create tone generator, that will generate sine, square, triangle and saw wave. I don't know how to make those waves with freq defined by user, and play many sounds at the time.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's not difficult to create a simple tone generator application.

Comment: I have something like this example. Already done some researches and know how to change frequency and multiple tones, but still trying to make it like I've posted above. (here is link to example of generating sine wave: [link](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/paex__write__sine_8c_source.html))

Comment: I can't help you with PortAudio but I can write a simple C++ function that generates a sine wave and accepts frequency and duration as parameters. This way you'll be able to understand more than just using the library (though I'm not saying there's anything wrong with using the library)

Comment: I would appreciate if you write it. Every help is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just give you a simple example (for a `sine wave`) and then you can create other types of waves you're interested in. The input parameters needed are

> - sampling rate (e.g 8000, 16000 etc)
> - amplitude (the actual values depend on the output format but it's best to have values in the range 0-1 and convert them to whatever format
>     you like/need)
> - frequency (expressed as a fraction of the sampling rate)
> - duration (in seconds)

The buffer length for tone data (samples) is determined by the `tone duration` in seconds multiplied by the `sampling rate`.

The actual code to create a sine wave may look something like the following

```
//global variables
const float PI = 3.141593;
const unsigned samplingRate = 8000;
const float amp = 0.8;

float *GenerateTone(float frequency, unsigned duration, unsigned &bufferLen){

     const float freq = frequency/samplingRate; //(e.g 440 / 8000 = 0,055)

     bufferLen = samplingRate * duration;

     float *buffer = new float[bufferLen]

     for(int i = 0; i < bufferLen; i++ ){

        buffer[i] = amp * sin(2 * PI*freq  * ((float)i)/samplingRate);

        }
    return buffer;
}
```

You can call this function like

```
unsigned len;
float *pTone = GenerateTone(440, 1, len);//len is an out parameter
...
delete [] pTone; //deallocatone memory when you no longer need it
```

In C++, you can also use `std::vector` to store the samples. This way you don't have to worry about memory allocation/deallocation.

```
std::vector<float> v; //make vector global  
const float PI = 3.141593;
const unsigned samplingRate = 8000;
const float amp = 0.8;

void GenerateTone(float frequency, unsigned duration){

  const amp = 0.8f;

  const float freq = frequency/samplingRate; 

  const unsigned len = samplingRate * duration; 
  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++ )
        v.push_back(amp * sin(2*PI*freq  * ((float)i)/sampleRate));

}
```

You can also pass amplitude as a paramater but in the examples above the amplitude is hardcoded. Also, see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave )

Answer (score 0):

The above program is a quick way to generate a audio tone.
Small correction:
Instead of

```
const float freq = frequency/samplingRate;
```

it should be:
`const float freq = frequency;`  // ie. pass the frequency directly into the sin()